# make a simple quiz with image as the questions and the answers

Tags: java, android

so i want to make a simple quiz with android studio. and then i have already make the quiz and it work so well. my quiz use text as the questions and the answers. instead of using text, i want to make an image as the questions and the answers as well. any suggestion to do that ? (sorry i'm very new to programming, and also this is my first semester)

here's the code of my previous quiz (text as the question and the answers)
code for question bank :

```
public class QuestionBank {

    private String textQuestions [] = {
            "1. What is the most populated country in the world ?",
            "2. Who is the first president of USA ?",
            "3. What animal that can fly ?",
            "4. 1000 + 945 = ?",
            "5. What year now ?"
    };

    // array of multiple choices for each question
    private String multipleChoice [][] = {
            {"Russia", "China", "USA", "Brazil"},
            {"Obama", "Vladimir Putin", "George Washington", "Donald Trump"},
            {"Fish", "Cat", "Bird", "Snake"},
            {"1999", "2018", "1945", "2000"},
            {"1999", "2000", "2010", "2018"}
    };

    private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {"China", "George Washington", "Bird", 
"1945", "2018"};

    public int getLength(){
        return textQuestions.length;
    }

    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        String question = textQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }

    public String getChoice(int index, int num) {
        String choice0 = multipleChoice[index][num-1];
        return choice0;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
        return answer;
    }
}
```

and here is the code for quiz activity code :

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private QuestionBank mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionBank();
    private TextView mScoreView;   
    private TextView mQuestionView;  
    private Button mButtonChoice1; 
    private Button mButtonChoice2; 
    private Button mButtonChoice3; 
    private Button mButtonChoice4; 

    private String mAnswer;  
    private int mScore = 0;  
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mScoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        mButtonChoice4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice4);
        updateQuestion();

        updateScore(mScore);
    }

    private void updateQuestion(){
        //
        if(mQuestionNumber<mQuestionLibrary.getLength() ){



mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));

mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 1));

mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 2));

mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 3));

mButtonChoice4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber,4));
            mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            mQuestionNumber++;
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "It was the last question!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, 
HighestScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass the current score to 
the second screen
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore+"/"+mQuestionLibrary.getLength());
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        //all logic for all answers buttons in one method
        Button answer = (Button) view;
        // if the answer is correct, increase the score
        if (answer.getText() == mAnswer){
            mScore = mScore + 1;
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Benar!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Salah!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        updateScore(mScore);
        updateQuestion();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply store the resource id's of the images in the arrays instead of the strings.

Comment: so what do i have to change from 'string' code ? 'ImageView' ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your string arrays ,write an array which stores the images from the drawable folder like this

```
   private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
    R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
```

Then in your xml instead of TextView you can use ImageView and instead of button you can use ImageButton.After that ,you can set your ImageView and ImageButton like

```
  imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds[1]));
```

Comment: The array code that you write was for the questions or the answers? As you can see i have 2 arrays in my program

Comment: it was an example meant to make you understand what you can do.If you want both the question and the answer as an image then change both of them otherwise just one.